# Issue with comma separated values (Carto)

Tags: javascript, cartodb, cartocss

I'm using the official [Carto library](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto) to parse [CartoCSS](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/):

```
cartocss = "#views { line-color: #7B00B4; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 0.7; line-dasharray: 4,2; }";

shader = new carto.RendererJS().render(cartocss),
style = shader.layers[0].getStyle({ property: 1 }, { zoom: 10 });

console.log({shader, style});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mz5xj67p/2/

The issue is the the value of `dasharray`. Although the style object has the correct value (`4, 2`) but when I try to retrieve it using `getStyle` method it just returns `4`.

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue, [this is a working example](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/dbccbbb35d2c0fcc62a4b2894f565263). What do you need those `render` methods?

Comment: @ramiroaznar Cause I'm using Mapbox GL and not leaflet.

Comment: If you are using Mapbox GL, you should use [CARTO VL](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/) instead of CARTO.js.

Comment: @ramiroaznar Oh! So all I have from the client js a a link to their viz.json and I'm able to extract tje SQL and CartoCSS from it to generate the styles. Can I do the same with CartoVL? From the examples, it looks like I still need to have the CartoCSS to create the styling object? Could you please provide an example? Thanks!!